# Entity Framework Code first + migrations and creating a new database

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, web-deployment, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS2012, framework 4.5, and Entity Framework 5.0 using code first and migrations.

I published my site using web deploy in which I changed the connection string to a new sql server 2008 db and turned on Execute Code First Migrations.

This all worked and the database tables where created but the seed method wasn't called.

Any ideas why the seed method wasn't called?

Comment: I'll add that even if I choose "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" on the Web Deploy options I am finding that the migrations are not running.  Does that help indicate something is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out my issue through trial and error.  It looks like in order to get the code first migrations to work in the project properties you need to turn on "Include all databases configured in Package/Publish SQL tab" and then go to those settings and ensure your connection string is listed and check in the Database Entries table.

This wasn't an obvious answer to me because it looked like code first migrations were handled using web deploy settings in the publish profile so having to do it in both places doesn't seem right.